# Finding the prime factorization of $2^{22}+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

The problem is

> Find the prime factorization of $2^{22}+1$

I have a solution but I think there must be some better ways:

**My Solution:**

$2^{22}+1 = (2^{22} + 2 \cdot 2^{11} +1) - 2 \cdot 2^{11} = (2^{11}+1)^2 - 2^{12}$

and we can factor as

$(2^{11}+1-2^6)(2^11+1+2^6) = (2048+1-64)(2048+1+64)= 1985 \cdot 2113$

From here it's not infeasible by hand, but I think there must be a better method.

Comment: You can factor it as $4^{11}+1^{11}=5(4^{10}-4^9+\dots +1)$ but this will give a worse result

Comment: In terms of cyclotomic polynomials,
$$2^{22}+1=\frac{2^{44}-1}{2^{22}-1}=\Phi_{44}(2)\Phi_4(2)=5\Phi_{22}(2^2)
=5\Phi_{11}(-4)$$
which is really not that useful...

Comment: The prime factors exceeding $5$ must be of the form $22k+1$. This allows you to find $397$ relatively quickly. The cofactor must already be prime because of $397^2>2113$. You can use this method also for the factors you already have found, in this case, you immediately see that $397$ is prime and for $2113$ , you see it almost immediately.

Comment: $2^{22}+1 = (2^{11}-2^{6}+1)\cdot (2^{11}+2^{6}+1)$ is an [Aurifeuillean factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization).

Comment: Oh that's nice to know it has a name. It came to mind from the way of factoring $x^4+1$. There is something similar known as the Sophie Germaine identity https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Sophie_Germain_Identity

Comment: 2113 is prime, so... by hand is difficult everyway

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p$ is a prime factor of $2^{22}+1$ greater than $5$.  Then $2^{22}\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.  So we know the order of $2$ modulo $p$ is $44$, and thus $44 \mid p-1$.  We conclude that $p = 44n+1$ for some $n$.

Using your factorization, we have that $\sqrt{2113} = 45.96\ldots$.  There are no primes of the form $44n+1$ in the range between $5$ and $45$, so $2113$ is prime.  To factor $1985$, the $5$ is easy, and we're left with $397$.  Again, there are no primes of the form $44n+1$ in the range $5$ to $\sqrt{397}$, so it's prime too.